# Sharing VPN Connection from Windows PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, network-adapter, connection-sharing

There are some questions similar to this one, but none highlights my specific problem.

Most VPNs connect through a Network Adapter which can then be used to share the connection either through the built-in internet connection sharing in its properties or through apps like Connectify, in which you can select the specific Network Adapter's connection you want to share.

But the VPN I use doesn't, or at the least, doesn't show up among the Network Adapters. I can't get a different VPN because I'm in a restricted country and this particular VPN is the only one that works for me consistently.

Is there any way I can share the VPN's connection from my PC to my devices?

Comment: Which VPN service it is? It's strange that it doesn't create a Network Adapter.

Comment: @harrymc It's called 12VPN, Website: "blockthis.xyz". It works seamlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the
[documentation](https://12vpn.net/understanding-the-openvpn-log/all-tap-win32-adapters-on-this-system-are-currently-in-use/),
12VPN does create a network adapter.

This adapter may be called "TAP-Win32 Adapter V9" or similar.
You may look for it in
*Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Change adapter options*,
under the columns of either "Name" or "Device Name".
The VPN must be activated for the adapter to be listed.

Once you locate the adapter, you may try and bridge it with the WiFi adapter.
Whether this will work or not is dependent on factors that are not under your
control.